# Ошибка при изменении pakage name в проекте

Tags: android

Здравствуйте , изменяю имя проекта по интрукции

Right click on the package name then Refract > Rename.
Right click on the project name Android tools > Rename Application Package.

Но удивительным образом, после смены pakage name , приложение вылетает на ViewActivity с ошибкой, подскажите пожалуйста,в чем может быть проблема.

Манифест до :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nproject.nice.list"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.ViewActivity"
        android:label="Просмотр"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="nproject.nice.list.ViewActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.List"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.Third"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_third" >

    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Манифест после:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nproject.fun.app"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.ViewActivity"
        android:label="Просмотр"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="nproject.nice.list.ViewActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.List"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nproject.nice.list.Third"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_third" >

    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

......
Upgrade

01-16 18:15:50.382: W/dalvikvm(2991): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bc7930)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nproject.fun.app/nproject.fun.app.ViewActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1249)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5063)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 18:15:50.382: W/System.err(2991): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:939)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:921)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at nproject.fun.app.ViewActivity.readRawTextFile(ViewActivity.java:255)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at nproject.fun.app.ViewActivity.onCreate(ViewActivity.java:201)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5150)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-16 18:15:50.392: W/System.err(2991):     ... 11 more
01-16 18:15:50.392: V/GAV3(2991): Thread[main,5,main]: Tracking Exception: NotFoundException (@ViewActivity:readRawTextFile:255) {main}
01-16 18:15:50.392: V/GAV3(2991): Thread[main,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
01-16 18:15:50.392: V/GAV3(2991): Thread[main,5,main]: Passing exception to original handler.
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nproject.fun.app/nproject.fun.app.ViewActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1249)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5063)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:939)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:921)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at nproject.fun.app.ViewActivity.readRawTextFile(ViewActivity.java:255)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at nproject.fun.app.ViewActivity.onCreate(ViewActivity.java:201)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5150)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-16 18:15:50.392: E/AndroidRuntime(2991):     ... 11 more
01-16 18:15:50.402: I/Ads(2991): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":2,"session_id":"9268776159637195698","seq_num":"3","slotname":"a152c1bd3a5ce9c","u_w":1280,"msid":"nproject.fun.app","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"imbf":"8009","net":"wi","app_name":"3.android.nproject.fun.app","hl":"ru","smart_w":"full","gnt":0,"u_audio":3,"u_sd":1.5,"ms":"Ja36P9KdiBeURDTcfqMMOX03GHXrEL6umyGOyVaEvPXW2DK0wDEaIo31QTgP8F60GPsPk5pMqVmSVMTqopTRw85M1fdgHjwIsJ6BuDGsBHcUaFdTNs7HiXI5KqUHXFpDzRJPRaeGYlLhlDMV8LlW1ol_JTQsYunfXO35UNdQk14aJJJebnKe9lFMW_BiqoHWJOGDIZV4_rZAj3e5Bk1gpOH0C495YIAbj2jC79uQ3kwp5bFurE9YjTqJYQq54O_FRZA1Ox2mxeRtJ9juZwlYmCq4CuioCSNVcU-jz3GGNRk6Tm1N9vM-539cp_usmWRUwL5oXoQvXUkv5kWvKOyvJw","mv":"80250010.com.android.vending","isu":"91CCB7302C67ADA5A1D8EC1E2D2B8A75","format":"1280x90_mb","oar":0,"smart_h":"auto","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":800,"pt":0,"bas_on":0,"ptime":3376});</script></head><body></body></html>

Comment: @Nproject, в лэйауте `ViewAcitivity` есть кастомные `View`?

Comment: @Nproject, ну и да, stacktrace исключения нужен, конечно же.

Comment: @falstaf, ну да все есть,весь прикол в том что c одним pakage name работает,а с другим нет =(

Comment: @Nproject, проверьте этот лэйаут, вполне вероятно, что `package name` этих кастомных `view` остался прежним, в следствии чего у вас и возникает ошибка на этапе инфлэйтинга. В любом случае, без стектрейса исключения остаётся лишь гадать, так что вы бы лучше всё же его добавили.

Comment: @falstaf,извините за глупый вопрос, но как можно посмотреть pakage name у view ,я просто тут в layout нигде не могу найти где-бы посмотреть..

Comment: @Nproject, почему вы упорно скрываете от общественности стектрейс исключения? :) Чем раньше вы его выложите, тем раньше получить решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @falstaf, я не скрываю , я просто полный лобанчик,сейчас попробую написать его,и выложить...где только его писать нужно разобраться)))

вот написал в onCreate 
 defaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();      Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler);

далее  в методе


        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         // do something
         
         defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
  


только где бы посмотреть что вывело

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку комментарии к вопросу кончились, пишу тут.

Вам нужно просто-напросто скопировать стектрейс исключения из `LogCat`'а.

Comment: вот что выдает LogCat,это то что нужно?=)

01-16 18:04:11.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 18:04:11.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nproject.fun.app/nproject.fun.app.ViewActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-16 18:04:11.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
01-16 18:04:11.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)

Comment: Да, это то, но вы скопировали далеко не весь стектрейс и самое интересное осталось за кадром.

Comment: @falstaf, добавил в конец посте из за размеров комментариев,надеюсь сейчас не промазал) вот скрин начиная с ошибки

http://gyazo.com/0c06361434c6e205905e9b3534581cfa

Comment: А теперь покажите, что находится на 255-й строке `ViewActivity.java`, в методе `readRawTextFile()`.

Comment: @falstaf, Ура!!!!!!Спасибо тебе огроменное! Блин,какой же я тормоз!6 часов блин потратил на такую фигню!

String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "nproject.fun.app"));

я вот тут забыл исправить,нужно срочно учиться нормально читать логи!facepalm

и вообще использовать объявленные отдельно string, что бы в куче кода не приходилось искать такое)))

Answer (score 0):

Переименовать то ты переименовал, а nproject.nice.list.ViewActivity так и оставил. Поменяй во всех activity название package на новый.

Comment: Дело в том, что они и лежали в nproject.nice.list .

Сейчас изменил везде в манифесте nproject.nice.list на nproject.fun.app ( новый) , перенес все .java в pakage nproject.fun.app + прописал у них вверху package nproject.fun.app;

Все осталось точно так же, 2 активити работают нормально на ViewActivity вылетает, причем если сменить pakage name обратно, то не вылетает.....

Comment: Вообще, чтоб не было такой путаницы, пиши в <activity android:name=".ViewActivity" > Тогда оно будет искать там, где прописано <manifest package="nproject.fun.app" ...>
Кроме того не очень понятно зачем во ViewActivity intent-filter, попробуй просто удалить его. А если ты все таки используешь его, проверь, что ты в коде action тоже поменял.